# Replace ids with actual values when using eloquent to display results

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have 3 tables as shown below:

```
table1
id
name
..
..


table2
id
table1_id
table3_id
name
..
..


table3
id
name
..
..
```

table1 has one-to-many relationship with table2 and

table2 has table3_id whose actual names are in table3

I would like to show all the info in single table. which is something like this:

**table1_id, table1_name, table3_id (this should simply get replaced by table3_name)**

my query:

```
// this gets me 2 tables together 
// Query 1    
$tables = Table1::with('table2')->get();

// this gets me 1 table3
// Query 2
$table3 =  Table3::all();
```

Query 1 Result:

```
[
 {                      // ROW 1
 id : 1,                //COL 1
 name: 'some name',     //COL 2
 ..
 ..
 table2 : [
  { 
   "id" : 1,
   "table1_id" : 1,    
   "name" : "some name",
   "table3_id" : 1        //COL 3
  },
  { 
   "id" : 2,
   "table1_id" : 1,
   "name" : "some name",
   "table3_id" : 2        //COL 4
  },
  { 
   "id" : 3,
   "table1_id" : 1,
   "name" : "some name",
   "table3_id" : 3        //COL 5
  }
 ]
},
{                         // ROW 2
 id : 1,                  // COL 1
 name: 'some name',       // COL 2
 ..
 ..
 table2 : [
  { 
   "id" : 1,
   "table1_id" : 1,
   "name" : "some name",
   "table3_id" : 1       //COL 3
  },
  { 
   "id" : 2,
   "table1_id" : 1,
   "name" : "some name",
   "table3_id" : 2       //COL 4
  },
  { 
   "id" : 3,
   "table1_id" : 1,
   "name" : "some name",
   "table3_id" : 3       //COL 5
  }
 ]
}
]
```

**COL 3, Col 4, Col 5 currently has id's printed but I want names to be printed.**

Query 2 Result (Table 3):

```
[
{
 "id" : 1,
 "name" : "some name in table 3"
},
{
 "id" : 2,
 "name" : "some name in table 3"
},
{
 "id" : 3,
 "name" : "some name in table 3"
}
]
```

## My Solution

```
@foreach( $tables as $table)
   <tr>
     <td>{{ $table->id }}</td>
     <td>{{ $table->name }}</td>
   @foreach($table->table2 as $table2)
     <td>{{ $table2->table3_id}}</td>
   @endforeach
     <td>{{ $tables->other_fields}}</td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

How to modify this code to replace ID's by Names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query for nested relationships using `with`. Just supply the name of the relation using dot notation:

```
$tables = Table1::with(['table2', 'table2.table3'])->get();
```

As long as you have proper foreign keys established, that will pull the entire record for each row in `table3` related to `table2`.

Here is the documentation on [eager loading nested relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).